# Can't get jquery function to execute

Tags: html, jquery, django

For the life of me I can't figure out why I can't get `JQuery` functions to operate in my `HTML`.

I have this `HTML` file and this simple `JQuery` "click" function that I have been using to test if things are working:

```
{% extends "home/home-base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block js-sub %}
  <script>
    $(".like").click(function(){
      console.log("this worked")
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
      console.log("NOPE")// jQuery is NOT available
    } else {
      console.log("WORKING")// jQuery is available
    }
  </script>
{% endblock js-sub %}

{% block home %}
  {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{ post.content }}</p>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="like" >Like</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock home %}
```

I am trying to call the "Like" button with the "like" class but can't seem to get anything to post to the console on the click.

I added the `if` function just to make sure JQuery was loaded and I do get "WORKING" posted to the console every time I load the page.

I have also tried typing the same "click" function directly into the console and it works then.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: $("like") should $(".like") missing the period in selector.

Comment: Sorry, I have the class selector in my actual file.  Must have deleted it somehow when writing the post.  I went back and updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$(".like").click(function(){
    console.log("this worked")
});
```

You are missing class selector in jQuery

EDIT:

Try to move `script block` to the bottom of the file, because you could be binding the event before the like button is ready and try it this way:

```
{% extends "home/home-base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block home %}
  {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{ post.content }}</p>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" class="like" >Like</button>
          </div>
        </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock home %}
{% block js-sub %}
  <script>
    $(".like").on('click', function(){
      console.log("this worked")
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
      console.log("NOPE")// jQuery is NOT available
    } else {
      console.log("WORKING")// jQuery is available
    }
  </script>
{% endblock js-sub %}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, yes that's actually how it is in my file.  I will edit the post

Comment: was the problem missing the class selector?

Comment: No, my actual HTML file has the class selector and it does not work.  That was just an error in the post

Comment: OK, so that didn't work, but then I tried just moving the `script` tags to the bottom (right before the `enblock` and it worked.  Any Idea what is going on?

Comment: I think this is what I mentioned also, you were trying to bind your event before your Dom was loading

Comment: @tsmith41094 The solution is in the answer given above.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks guys!